# how can repeat signup aws cognito [solve]

Tags: python-3.x, flask, amazon-cognito

solve is here [gist](https://gist.github.com/clucle/05f493b7ba7f432ef01bdfd5c6f0c34b)

when sign up in our app, sign up with aws cognito and send verify email with code.

if user close app not input verify, user have to re sign up. (saved in cognito userpool state UNCONFIRM)

and it occur two problem.

1. password may be changed (when re sign up)
2. renew verify code

my code is here python3 and warrant

```
@app.route('/signup/', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    u = Cognito(os.getenv('COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID'), os.getenv('COGNITO_CLIENT_ID'),
            user_pool_region=os.getenv('COGNITO_REGION'))

    u.add_base_attributes(name=user_name, email=user_email)
    u.register(user_email, user_password)
    return redirect(url_for('lobby'))
```

err code

*botocore.errorfactory.UsernameExistsException: An error occurred (UsernameExistsException) when calling the SignUp operation: An account with the given email already exists.*

**how to re signup with renew password, and send new verify email**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, i solve

```
@app.route('/signup/', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    idp_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    '''
    resp = idp_client.sign_up(ClientId=app_client_id,
                              Username=user_email,
                              Password=user_password,
                              UserAttributes=[{'Name': 'email', 'Value': user_email}])
    '''
    resp = idp_client.resend_confirmation_code(ClientId=os.getenv('COGNITO_CLIENT_ID'),
                                           Username=user_email)

    print(resp) #check result
    return redirect(url_for('lobby'))
```

use boto3 i want (resend not acquire password)